# Merging PHP static arrays

Tags: php, arrays

As a code reuse measure, I'd like embed existing static arrays when creating new static arrays. E.G.:

```
public static $a = array(1, 2, 3);
public static $b = array(4, 5, 6);
public static $c = array_merge(self::$a, self::$b);
```

I'd rather type $c = array_merge(self::$a, self::$b) than type $c = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6).

PHP won't allow me to use array_merge. How to do this? Thanks

Comment: Correct, you can't execute functions when initializing a variable regardless of whether or not it's a static variable.  If you must do this, use Niet's idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this was a lot of work, I decided to convert the class from purely static variables and functions to one that is instantiated. This in the long run appears to be the best way to get the benefits I'm looking for.

IE converted the static variables to instance variables and the definitions take place in the constructor.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
public static function initVars() {
    self::$c = array_merge(self::$a,self::$b);
}
```

You can call `className::initVars()` immediately after the class's definition - if you're using an autoloader this method can be particularly effective for initialisation (for instance with a DB or Memcache wrapper class)

Comment: I would also set `$a` and `$b` in this function for maximum clarity

Comment: That is interesting and will consider it and let you know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, however, I can't really think of a situation where this type of complexity would be essential.

I would think that you'd have to have some profiling telling you this was called a huge number of times for it to be anything more than a micro-optimization to put an init in the class definition.  Depending on the size of the arrays, what are you really gaining over just hand merging the arrays in the definition?

It seems as if you are conflating [static variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php#language.variables.scope.static) with class constants, in terms of how you are dealing with these, because, IF your code changes either $a or $b, the computed $c array will NOT reflect the change.

With that said, the limitations of class constants certainly does push someone towards a static variable if you're going to be creating a lot of instances of the class.

Just as devil's advocate, if $c is truly a derived array, you could just as easily have a method in your class you'd use to get access to the merged array:

```
protected getC() {
    return array_merge($this->$a, $this->$b);
}
```

That would be safer if there is any chance that the static variables could be changed.